# external mail service

Tags: email

Maybe this is a bit of an ovious question or somehow unrelated. Sorry for that, i digged but could not find an answer anywhere.

I am running a drupal based site on amazon servers. The site uses some mail functionalities. New user confirmation,  updates, mail subscriptions, basic things.

Problem is that most of the emails sent by my server end up in the junk boxes because amazon IPs are not welcome. They are often used by spammers and you get blacklisted even if you never spammed.

Can anyone suggest me how to avoid this? Either to set up some other mail server outside amazon ip range, so any mail request generated on my server is actually being send from elsewhere. But how is this technically done? Or if there is anything I can do on my server so I dont get into junk folders?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon's EC2 IP ranges are basically scorched earth from a spam filter perspective. They're blacklisted or heavily penalized by most major ISPs.

You can send e-mail via any number of third-parties. Amazon themselves has one (Amazon SES), and I've played with Mandrill, SendGrid, and Postmark personally and been happy with all three.

Comment: how is it technically achieved (in a few words) sending from the third party? A setting for the PHP to use sendmail() function externally? Sorry but I completely lack the understanding of this one. If you would be so kind to point me into the right direction I will then research on the details... Thanks

Comment: You'd configure sendmail (or postfix or whatever MTA you're using) to use an external SMTP server. You should be able to find docs for your MTA on specifying credentials and server locations.

Comment: OK. Got it. I think I will try doing it with Amazon SES - they promise to deliver everything this way. It still would be within their network for me. Up to 2000 emails per day is way more than I need.